# how to handle Ctrl+D using GNU Readline

Tags: c, shell, readline

I'm trying to read a line from stdin using the GNU Readline Library. I have two major problems (I think): one is the PROMPT and the other one is handling Crtl+D (which is supposed to exit the minishell, but seg faults instead) 
How can I handle Ctrl+D so that it can exit?
This is the code where I use readline() functions:

```
char* readl(char* line){
    char* string="";
    char* pitos="";
    pitos=getenv("USER");
        strcat(pitos,PROMPT);
        strcat(pitos," ");
    while(strcmp(string,"")==0){


        //printf("%s%s ",getenv("USER"),PROMPT);
        string = readline (pitos);
    }
    if(!string){ #trying to exit when ctrld
        exit(0);
    }else{
        char* com = strchr(string,'#'); #ignore comments
        if(com!=NULL){
            *com=NULL;
        }
        add_history(string);
        strcpy(line,string);
        return string;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to alter the Environment Table with the pointer from `pitos=getenv("USER");`? Even if the memory at the pointer is writable, how do you know if there is room to `concat` onto its entry? You are supposed to use `putenv` to modify an environment variable.

Comment: Why have you changed the code? There is no need to invalidate the comments and answers. Just change you own code, ask another question if you still have trouble. It is better to go away and think about things, than try to indulge in real-time tutorial.

Comment: Rolled back. You are supposed not to change your question if that invalidates an answer. Feel free to **add** more information, but don't change relevant parts of the existing text and mark the edits appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

```
char* pitos="";
pitos=getenv("USER");
    strcat(pitos,PROMPT);
    strcat(pitos," ");
```

There is just 1-byte available in the string pointed to by `pitos` (the terminating `'\0'`), and it is undefined behavior to write to it.

Answer (score 0):

One problem appears to be that you call `strcmp()` on the result of `readline()` before testing it for NULL.

Try this:

```
while(string && strcmp(string,"")==0){
    ...
```

Comment: I have updated the code, but CtrlD doesn't work. It still seg faults